# How can I fix 'no matches found: enode` error when setting up private geth nodes?

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, bootnodes, enode

I'm following along with [a tutorial from the geth ethereum.org documentation](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/private-network#ethash-example). The tutorial is describing how to set up a private network of multiple geth nodes.

I have run the

```
bootnode -nodekey boot.key -addr :30305
```

it successfully returns, and I keep it running

```
enode://148cc729f30b1bf36fcb538e77c6820d6c80f20378cfe5e21dc0e3349f102830bfd8e2319863741f63a3f720a47f176fa9f41723a78da8405eb61c86b75cff79@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30305
Note: you're using cmd/bootnode, a developer tool.
We recommend using a regular node as bootstrap node for production deployments.
INFO [08-13|23:38:21.813] New local node record                    seq=1,691,941,101,812 id=c4699cfd1ff4c162 ip=<nil> udp=0 tcp=0
```

then I open another terminal and try

```
./geth --datadir node1 --port 30306 --bootnodes enode://148cc729f30b1bf36fcb538e77c6820d6c80f20378cfe5e21dc0e3349f102830bfd8e2319863741f63a3f720a47f176fa9f41723a78da8405eb61c86b75cff79@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30305 --networkid 12345 --unlock 0x3f57d97b5197c0200ab4f6442201f1af9d1e8d10 --password node1/password.txt --authrpc.port 8551
```

it returns:

```
no matches found: enode://148cc729f30b1bf36fcb538e77c6820d6c80f20378cfe5e21dc0e3349f102830bfd8e2319863741f63a3f720a47f176fa9f41723a78da8405eb61c86b75cff79@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30305
```

What is causing this error and how can I fix this?

Comment: Please include all relevant information and code inside your question body, this allows users to help you without having to click on external links. Thanks for understanding!

Comment: thanks for your advice ! I have modified my question@RohanNero

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution. The enode link should be enclosed in double quotation marks, like this:

./geth --datadir node1 --port 30306 --bootnodes "enode://a22ad2ab569792093d608a77b788f702641f96b045d7d44ab739ebb0c27956cf16e4d6ffbdb27eb3b98a58ebdf3681733386c9205203544fd799fa64bc7c7cda@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30305" --networkid 123454321 --unlock 0x802755E6151646Dab88E9d681349CA516CaAD9B5 --password node1/password.txt --authrpc.port 8551 --mine --miner.etherbase 0x802755E6151646Dab88E9d681349CA516CaAD9B5